# How do I only out put the rows that have column values from a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame and a vector. I want to output only the rows from the data frame that have values in a column in common with the vector v.

For example:

```
v = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

df =

```
     A    B
1    a    2
2    b    6 
3    c    4 
4    d    1
5    e    8
```

What I want to do is, if df$b has any values of v in it then output the row. Basically if df$b[i] isn't in v then remove the row for i= 1:nrows(df)

output should be

```
     A    B
1    a    2
2    c    4 
3    d    1
```

since 2,4 and 1 are in v.

Comment: You said it yourself -- "2, 4 and 1 are **in** v". See the 2nd result on Google for "in r"

Comment: @MichaelChirico - A blog about pipes?  That's the second hit for me when I google "in R"

Comment: i see. that's third for me. this is second: https://www.google.com/search?q=in+r&oq=in+r&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j0l3.342j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: For me the pipe blog comes second when incognito, but I get the value matching page in normal mode

Answer (score 3):

You should make use of the `%in%` operator.

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- read.table(text =
"     A    B
1    a    2
2    b    6
3    c    4
4    d    1
5    e    8", header = TRUE)

out <- df[df$B %in% v, ]
```

This gives:

```
  A B
1 a 2
3 c 4
4 d 1
```